# JavaScript RSS reader not creating dynamic HTML list

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, rss, rss-reader

I am attempting to display an unordered list, created dynamically with JavaScript, inline. It is apparent to me that my JavaScript is not actually creating an unordered list like I thought it would, so I am unable to apply styles to it. The RSS feed is added to HTML like so:

```
<head>
 <script src="lib/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="src/jquery.rss.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery(function($) {
        $("#rss-feeds").rss("http://www.feed43.com/channelfireball.xml", {
          limit: 15
       })
     })
 })
</head>
<body>
<div class="post_results" id="rss-feeds"></div>
</body>
```

Thank you for any tips. I'm using sdepold's [jquery.rss plugin](https://github.com/sdepold/jquery-rss).

Comment: Try wrapping your code in a [`document.ready` block](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! After googling how to use it and attempting to add the block I only succeeded in breaking the feed. It no longer displays. I apologize for my ignorance. I updated my post to reflect the changes to the HTML.